# Not reading all of file

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm trying to use a simple decryption algorithm to decrypt some files. The code I have so far will work for the most part, but stop reading after a few hundred bytes and export what it has. 
Example, I have a .X file, it's 14.7KB. I run it through the program and it comes out as 643 bytes.
The current code is here: http://pastebin.com/aNNjYTzg
Since the code formatting for this site is driving me insane...

I just added in the algorithm to existing code, so most of it is not used.

EDIT:

```
    cout << "Enter the name of your file to " << encrypt_decrypt[choice-1] << ": ";
    cin >> filename;
    in.open(filename);

    getline(in,buffer);

    void encryptdecrypt(const string buffer,const char map[],int len,string& newbuffer)
    {
    int i=0;
    char t;
    char code;
    for (i=0;i<buffer.length();i++)
    {
            t=buffer[i];
            (t += 251 - ((i * 14) & 255));
            cout << "Buffer length: " << buffer.length() << endl;
            cout << "newbuffer length: " << newbuffer.length() << endl;
            newbuffer.push_back(t);
    }
    newbuffer.push_back('\n');
    }
    out << newbuffer;
```

EDITx2:
Reads the whole file, but only beginning parts are decrypted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Materi
+"Òû%÷*&$'
ëÐ!ÐÎ&"# ëÐ"!Ý "

Ü"ÐÎÝì»¸
```

Comment: I'm guessing the file is "binary", and you are trying to read it as text...

Comment: Please post the interesting part here, you can't expect us to dive through lines and lines of unused code …

Comment: it's not hard to format code on this site; highlight the code then press ctrl+k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given that the result of `(t += 251 - ((i * 14) & 255))` is any value in the character range, you will need to read and write the file as a "binary" file, or the content won't "work".

This means that you need to use `stream::read` to read a block of data and `stream::write` to write data to the output file, and when you open the file, you need to supply `ifstream::binary` and `ofstream::binary` respecitvely as the mode.

A text input (when you don't specify `binary` in the mode) will interpret certain input bytes as `end of file` (stopping the input) and other input bytes as `newline` characters (which, if you use `getline` will be ignored on input). Since in your encrypted form, you don't use those characters to mean exactly those things, you should not use text-based input (the encrypted file isn't a text file).

Comment: It now reads the whole file, but only the beginning part of it is decrypted.

Comment: Sorry, without understanding exactly where in your code this goes wrong, I can't say. I'm pretty sure that storing binary data "as if it is text" in an XML document is a bad idea in general. You may want to at least post your new code...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't think he's storing unescaped binary in XML; it looks like the XML itself is being "decrypted" from binary.

Comment: I just added ", ios::binary" after filename in "in.open(filename)" and "out.open(filename)"

Comment: Right, so you completely ignored the part about "use read and write to get data from and to the file, then..." - getline doesn't work on things that aren't "lines" - especially if you have something that looks like a newline to the input, but it should actually translate to some completely different character in decryption - but it's getting lost because getline is "skipping it".